# Angular; Error: Component NewPharmacyComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

NewPharmacy component is part of the Provider module's declarations array and I have imported Provider module in app.module.ts still I'm getting the error Component `NewPharmacyComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

provider.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NewpharmacyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProviderRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class ProviderModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
  import {ProviderModule} from './views/provider/provider.module'



   @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ProviderModule

  ],
```

I'm not able to figure out the issue.What's wrong with the code?

Comment: If you use the component outside of the declaring module you must list it under `exports` in addition to `declarations`. Also, the name provider module is really confusing

Comment: @AluanHaddad `Can't export directive NewPharmacyComponent from ProviderModule as it was neither declared nor imported!` How to make sure component is inside a specific module?

Comment: You have to declare _and_ export it

Comment: @AluanHaddad       ` @NgModule({
  declarations: [NewpharmacyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports:[NewPharmacyComponent]
})
export class ProviderModule { }` declared and exported still same error

Comment: That's odd indeed. That code is correct. Make sure your paths are correct and that you aren't declaring it somewhere else as well

Comment: My mistake , I've used NewPharmacyComponent instead of NewpharmacyComponent... ie capital P instead of small letter.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes, no error now ..just routing issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to export it to be used in other modules:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NewpharmacyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProviderRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [NewpharmacyComponent]
})
export class ProviderModule { }
```

Now the other components will have access to your NewpharmacyComponent.